# Why sys.conversation_endpoints can be empty?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have started using Service Broker. After reading article https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/managing-service-broker-conversations i have tried reuse conversation via selecting existing one from sys.conversation_endpoints:

```
    select  top 1
            @Handle = CEP.conversation_handle
    from    sys.conversation_endpoints CEP with(nolock)
    where   CEP.far_service = 'EventService'
            and CEP.state = 'CO'
            and CEP.is_initiator = 1
    order by CEP.lifetime desc
```

and it worked nice on stage. But after releasing to prod problem was found with selecting sys.conversation_endpoints - sometime it was empty, even with nolock, although there a lot of records when selecting in monitoring script. After spending several hours in google i can't found answer how it can be. Please, help me to understand how it can be to avoid it.

PS Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU17) (KB4515579) - 14.0.3238.1 (X64)

Comment: Are you looking on the initiator or target? Are you closing conversations?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in user who call my stored procedure, he does not have permissions to see some metadata info.